How to install a Linux alternative bare metal on Macbook Pro?
I installed Ubuntu on both an old MacBook Air (~2011) and a newer MacBook Pro (~2020). I am unsatisfied with Ubuntu in both machines and would love to try an alternative.
On the MacBook Pro, which represents the biggest problem, the keyboard, trackpad and wifi are not recognized. Also, the bootable USB drives I prepared are no longer recognized for whatever reason, which I suspect might be related. Some guidance into how to force boot would be appreciated.

It is unclear if you want help solving the problems, or if you want to abandon Ubuntu to try a different Linux distro ("alternative").

"the keyboard, trackpad and wifi are not recognized" generally ALL Linux use the same set of drivers  First make sure your system is compatible with another OS than Mac. "I am unsatisfied with Ubuntu in both machines and would love to try an alternative."  we only support official Ubuntu. And all of our systems use the same drivers. Heck, probably all Linux do.

Both comments are quite fair. In light of the situation pointed out, I would like to know where I can find the drivers. Much appreciated

For better driver support on recent Intel Macs, check out https://t2linux.org/ for step by step instructions of setting up the drivers. For ARM (M1/M2/M3) Macs, check out https://asahilinux.org/ (where most hardware work out of the box)

Please ask different questions for different laptops, and specify the issues with both.
